# Find the currently active Finder window/folder

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Is there any way to determine the currently active window, or a folder, in the Finder? I need this to determine, in some sense, an appropriate "default" location in which to do some particular things in my app.

Actually, does this question even make sense? Does this concept of a "currently active Finder window/folder" even exist in the first place? If it does not, I kindly ask how to get the currently **selected** Finder item.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the concept of the currently active Finder window does exist, as well as the currently selected item.

For example, the following AppleScript gets the `selection` which is the current selection in the frontmost window. Since this returns a list of files or folders even if there is a single item, the next line gets the first item out of that list (after making sure that the count of the list is greater than 0). You can then ask the Finder for the `container window` of the selected item, which will return a `Finder window` object.

```
tell application "Finder"
    set selectedItems to selection

    if ((count of selectedItems) > 0) then
        set selectedItem to (item 1 of selectedItems) as alias
        container window of selectedItem
    end if

end tell
```

<s>I'm pretty sure the code sidyll posted will work okay in 10.5 and earlier, but it errors out in 10.6 due to the inevitable changes and quirkiness that AppleScript seems to have from one version of OS X to the next.</s>

[EDIT] Actually, I just figured out what's going on.
I usually have the Finder's Inspector window open all the time (the dynamic Get Info window you get through Command-Option-i), the upper right panel in the image below:

[image]

That image shows 3 different classes of windows:

1) The upper left, a Get Info window, is an `information window`, which inherits from the generic `window` class.

2) The upper right, an Inspector window, is a plain `window`.

3) The lower image shows a `Finder window`, which inherits from the generic `window` class.

If I run the following script with the setup of windows shown above:

```
tell app "Finder"
    every window
end tell
```

it returns the following result:

> {***window*** "mdouma46 Info" of *application*
>   "Finder", ***information window*** "mdouma46
>   Info" of *application* "Finder", ***Finder
>   window*** id 1141 of *application*
>   "Finder"}

So, what was happening in my case is that, since the Inspector window is a floating utility panel, if it's currently being shown, asking the Finder for `window 1` will always return the Inspector panel, since it's always floating in front of the other windows.

So the error I was getting when running the code was:

> error "Can’t make «class fvtg» of
>   window 1 of application \"Finder\"
>   into type alias." number -1700 from
>   «class fvtg» of window 1 to alias

(In other words, the Inspector window, a plain `window`, doesn't have the FileViewer target (`fvtg`) property; only `Finder window`s do).

So, your code will work fine as long as the user doesn't have the Inspector window, the Preferences window, or a Get Info window that is frontmost. By changing `window` to `Finder window`, though, you can make sure that you only look at the file viewer windows that have the `target` property.

So, like this:

```
NSDictionary *errorMessage = nil;

NSAppleScript *script = [[[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:
    @"tell application \"Finder\"\n"
        " if ((count of Finder windows) > 0) then\n"
           "  return (POSIX path of (target of Finder window 1 as alias))\n"
        "end if\n"
     "end tell"] autorelease];

if (script == nil) {
    NSLog(@"failed to create script!");
    return nil;
}
NSAppleEventDescriptor *result = [script executeAndReturnError:&errorMessage];
if (result) {
    // POSIX path returns trailing /'s, so standardize the path
    NSString *path = [[result stringValue] stringByStandardizingPath];
    return path;
}
```

Comment: Very comprehensive answer! Anyway, my app was targeting 10.6; and just to confirm the script runs correctly here (with `window` only). Well, I'm not an AppleScript master, but certainly it's something to investigate.

Comment: @sidyll: Ah hah! You're right about the code. I figured out what the problem was. I've updated my answer with what was causing my problem.

Comment: Oh man, a lot of valuable information going on here. Thanks for sharing this, by the way I think it's time to release an update to my app :-) no one ever complained about the problem, probably because ⌥⌘I isn't a very well known feature, but that was a lucky play. I'd upvote more times if possible.

Answer (score 3):

I needed to do this in a project in the past and recurred to AppleScript:

```
// Get path
NSAppleScript *script = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:
                        @"tell application \"Finder\"\n"
                         "  return POSIX path of (target of window 1 as alias)\n"
                         "end tell"];
NSDictionary *errors = nil;
NSAppleEventDescriptor *descriptor = [script executeAndReturnError:&errors];

if ((errors != nil) || (descriptor == nil)) {
    // There is no opened window or an error occured
} else {
    // what was retrieved by the script
    path = [descriptor stringValue];
}
[script release];
```